# How to create different BigDecimal Objects each time?

Tags: java, java-8, java-11, bigdecimal

I have a piece of code as below:

```
{   ...........
    priceOverrideOption.setOverrideValue(buildOverrideValue(sequence));
}

private PaymentAmount buildOverrideValue(int sequence)
    {
        PaymentAmount paymentAmount = new PaymentAmount();
        BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(sequence*10);
        Money money = new Money();
        money.setValue(bigDecimal);
        money.setUnit(null);
        paymentAmount.setAmount(money);
        paymentAmount.setPercentage(null);
        return paymentAmount;
    }
```

Each time sequence changes from 1,2,3 so I expect something like below as output:

```
"overrideValue": {
                    "amount": {
                      "unit": null,
                      "value": 10
                    },
                    "percentage": null
                  },
"overrideValue": {
                    "amount": {
                      "unit": null,
                      "value": 20
                    },
                    "percentage": null
                  },
"overrideValue": {
                    "amount": {
                      "unit": null,
                      "value": 30
                    },
                    "percentage": null
                  }
```

But the result is value is always 10, it doesn't become 20 or 30. I understand BigDecimal is immutable. How can I achieve the result which I want?

Comment: probably `sequence` is 1 or you are using a unique `buildOverrideValue` result but I don't know what code are you running

Comment: The code you posted seems okay, I don't see anything wrong with it. That means the problem is probably somewhere else. Either `sequence` doesn't get the values that you think it does or the result is not used in the way you think (maybe the method doesn't even get called as you expect it). So we need more context to be able to tell what exactly is wrong.

Comment: A [mre], please?

Comment: Try `priceOverrideOption.setOverrideValue(buildOverrideValue(sequence++));`.

Comment: Side note: `new BigDecimal(sequence*10)` defeats the purpose of `BigDecimal` as the multiplication could overflow before the `BigDecimal` has been constructed. You’d rather use `BigDecimal.valueOf(sequence).multiply(BigDecimal.TEN)` or in this specific case the more efficient `BigDecimal.valueOf(sequence).movePointRight(1)`.